# insert via php function getting error

Tags: php, mysql

So I am trying to build a function (modifying another one) and I have the array posting fine to the function. It seems that the formating may be off for the INSERT command with my function. I have been looking for the past two hrs and can't find where I may have gone run.

Here is the function, Error code below!

```
public static function addCompany($toInsert = array()){
  self::construct();
  if( count($toInsert) == 0 ){
    echo "Nothing posted!";
  }else {
    $keys   = array_keys($toInsert);
    $columns = implode(",", $keys);
    $colVals = implode(",:", $keys);

  $sql = self::$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO companys {$columns} VALUES(:$colVals)");
  //$sql->bindValue(":id", $company);
  foreach($toInsert as $key => $value){
    $value = htmlspecialchars($value);
    $sql->bindValue(":$key", $value);
  }
  $sql->execute();
  return true;
 }
}
```

Here is the array coming in.

```
$vname = $_POST["name"];
$vlogo = $_POST["logo"];
$vinfo = $_POST["info"];
$vsite = $_POST["site"];
$vest = $_POST["est"];
$data = array('name' => $vname, 'logo' => $vlogo, 'info' => $vinfo, 'site' => $vsite, 'est' => $vest);
```

Here is the error.

> 2017/01/07 18:30:22 [error] 9682#9682: *3352 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'name,logo,info,site,est VALUES('test','test','test','test','test')' at line 1' in /var/www/xxxx/inc/xxxxxxx.php:938

Any help would be fantastic!

Comment: Why are you trying to build the columns/values like this? This is what the 4th question on this..

Comment: I would start by echoing the query you think you are building i.e. `$sql = "INSERT INTO companys {$columns} VALUES(:$colVals)"; echo $sql;` that should show you what a mess you are making of this

Comment: **http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html**

Comment: Why are you calling `htmlspecialchars` on your values? This just mangles them for no reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `INSERT` query is wrong, you missed the parentheses encapsulating the column names. See here,

```
$sql = self::$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO companys {$columns} VALUES(:$colVals)");
                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Your query statement should be like this:

```
$sql = self::$dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO companys ({$columns}) VALUES(:$colVals)");
```

Comment: You were the *Eagle Eye* on this one. I literally had to squint (my eyes) to see what they had. I guess I should have zoomed in.

Comment: @Fred-ii- *hahaha*, yeah, sometimes I also zoom in to look for probable syntax errors. :-)

Comment: It's because I'm running off a rather high res screen/resolution; it was a tad misleading. Good catch ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the help, been a long day :) That worked!